# How to set Port as Input for Push Button in C?

Tags: c, input, embedded, microcontroller, pic

I'm using MikroC to try and program my PIC16f62 Microcontroller. I've managed to get my outputs working (I can have LEDs turn on, etc) but I can't seem to get the inputs work.

Here is my current code:

```
void main() {
    TRISB.RB0 = 0; //set Port RB0 as output
    PORTB.RB0 = 1; //set Port RB0 to high (turn on LED)
    TRISA = 1; //Set PORTA as inputs 

    for(;;){  //endless loop
            if(PORTA.RA0 == 1){  //if push button is pressed
                         PORTB.RB0 = !PORTB.RB0;  \\toggle LED
            }
    }
}
```

I don't know if the problem is that I'm not configuring the PORT correctly or if I'm checking whether or not the button is pressed incorrectly.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you connected a scope to RA0 and RB0 - and what does it show with the button held down?

Comment: I added the embedded tag to this post. Include it in any question about micro-controllers and you will have a much higher chance of getting the right kind of people to read and answer it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This change may help you.

```
for(;;){  //endless loop
        if(PORTA.RA0 == 1){  //if push button is pressed
                     PORTB.RB0 = !PORTB.RB0;  \\toggle LED
          while(PORTA.RA0 == 1);
       /*wait till button released as press of a buttons take time  and processor is too fast */
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are probably reading the port pin correctly, however because you're toggling the LED on and off when you detect a press, your eye can't see the result.

For example, a clock rate of 1Mhz will have the on/off toggle approximately 150,000 times per second (1,000,000 cycles / ~3 ASM instructions per loop / 2 loops to turn on then off).

I would suggest taking the approach of having the LED match the state of the input pin.

```
for(;;)
{
  if(PORTA.RA0 == 1) //if button is pressed
  {
    PORTB.RB0 = 1;   //turn on LED
  }
  else
  {
    PORTB.RB0 = 0;   //turn off LED
  }
}
```

This technique is similar to what Rajesh suggested, but provides a bit more direct feedback on whether the input pin is set or not.

If that doesn't work, then something with your setup of the TRISA is not correct.  You may want to try this:

```
TRISA.RB0 = 1;
```